# Recommended or not: Sending a JSON body via POST HTTP Request without modification

Tags: rest, http

Is it recommended to send a JSON body via a POST HTTP Request which doesn't modify anything?

Based on the link below, a Get request is not recommended to have a body. Thus, the other way is the one above.

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Example:
Get the list of users, or anything for that matter based on parameters.

```
Http GET example.com/users
Body
{
 name:"John",
 age:1,
 ... long list of parameters
}
```

Comment: Why would it be a POST if it doesn't modify anything...?

Comment: If a request does not modify anything, why does it need a body? Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: pls see example.

Comment: POST doesn't _need_ to modify anything AFAIK, it just _can_. I've seen POST being used in this case too, where the URL would become too big to take all possible filters into account. You could append `/search` to your path, e.g. `POST /users/search`, in the sense "create a new search".

Comment: It certainly doesn’t *have* to modify anything (see the entirety of the SOAP protocol) but it wouldn’t be compliant with the HTTP spec and can cause significant confusion with developers trying to consume such a service. IMO, the most spec-compliant way to accomplish this would be to implement the route as a GET and use URL parameters to pass arguments for the information retrieval operation. Depending on the use case, you could implement a single URL parameter that accepts URL-encoded JSON, but that isn’t a particularly common pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it recommended to send a JSON body via a POST HTTP Request which doesn't modify anything?

The rule is that [POST is the default](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post); it should be used unless there is something better.

For a request with "effectively read only" semantics, you want to use GET instead of POST... *if it works*.  The challenge can be those cases where the request-target (aka: the URI) gets long enough that you start running into [414 URI Too Long](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.12) responses.  If your identifier is long enough that general purpose components refuse to pass the request along, then it is not something better, and you fall back to POST.

> An origin server SHOULD NOT rely on private agreements to receive content, since participants in HTTP communication are often unaware of intermediaries along the   request chain. ([HTTP Semantics, 9.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics/))

In other words, introducing a private agreement to include content in a GET request trades away inter-op, which - if you want "web scale" - is not a winning trade.  So GET-with-a-body is not better, and you fall back to POST.

The HTTP working group has been working on semantics for a new "effectively-read-only-with-a-body" method token, which could prove to be an alternative for requests where you need to include a bunch of information in the body because it is too long to encode it into the URI.  But we don't have a standard for that today, which means that it is not something better, and you fall back to POST.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.